# Share apt upgrade packages between systems on the same lan

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, lan

I have a bunch of clusters of Raspberry with Raspberry OS installed, they have all the same configuration and the same packages installed. I want to keep them updated but they are connected to Internet with a limited bandwidth connection. Is there a way to set a master system that downloads the packages to upgrade and the others refer to it instead to download several times the same packages? I think I should use the sources.list file on the slaves but I don't know how to set the server if this is the way to do it

Comment: [see that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look